# Need to extract words from string in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract the names from the following string:

```
$contact = "John96783819Dickson97863424"
```

i tried using this:

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/',$contact,$matches);
```

but i get an array with all the alphabets individually in the array.

### Desired Output:

```
Array ([0] => 'John', [2] => 'Dickson')
```

And now it gets complicated. The same reggae should extract this

$contact = 'Vincent Tan96123179Lawrence Thoo90603123Ryan Ong91235721'
into this

```
Array ([0] => 'Vincent Tan', [2] => 'Lawrance Thoo' , [3] => 'Ryan Ong')
```

How do i do that?

Comment: Ok found the answer to my question. [a-z A-Z]+ will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to  quantify the character class using `+`

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/
```

- `+` matches one occurence of presceding regex

Example : http://regex101.com/r/bI6aH1/1

```
preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z]+/',$contact,$matches);
```

Will give output  as

```
Array ( [0] => John [1] => Dickson )
```

Comment: and `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 0):

```
 preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/',$contact,$matches);
```

The /[a-zA-Z]/ means match any ONE letter, anywhere in the string. Adding the + in /[a-zA-Z]+/ means match one or MORE sequential letters.